# How to distinguish the sounds of the two vowels in Korean ᅭ ᅲ?

Tags: pronunciation, vowel

How to distinguish the sounds of the two vowels in Korean ᅭ ᅲ?

Am I correct to make the following comparison in American English:

- ㅛ is the same as yo-yo;
- ㅠ is the same as "book" where 'b' is changed to y?

Comment: Agree with Lee M.U., and I will add that some native speakers make them sound almost the same, to my ears…

Answer (score 1):

We pronounce ㅛ as `yo`, as you guessed.
ex)

- 요리(cooking) is pronounced as `yo(요)li(리)`
- 요청(request) is pronounced as `yo(요)cheong(청)`

But, We pronounce ㅠ as `yu` (or `you` in some cases, maybe).
ex)

- 우유(milk) is pronounced as `u(우)yu(유)`
- 유재석(Korean comedian) is pronounced as `Yu(유) Jae(재)-seok(석)`